# .htaccess :: Cannot set a upload_tmp_dir

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload, apc, ini-set

Looks like a very simple task but it's not working...
I'm trying to set `upload_tmp_dir` to the ROOT directory on my .htaccess file...

```
php_value upload_tmp_dir /
```

I'm printing out the results and it's stays the same as the default on my php.ini

```
echo 'Your Temp Upload Directory : '.ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').'<br>';
```

IOW... not working.

I know that it's impossible to set it via :

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','/');
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you check if your apache is configured to allow .htaccess? by default it isn't.

Comment: yes other parameters working perfectly so .htaccess IS working properly !

Comment: Make sure the path is writable

Answer (score 1):

> The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever > user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.
>
> If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

as you can see on [ini.upload-tmp-dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

So check if **open_basdir** is on and new directory is writeable (which i think will not be writable you set it to root

Answer (score 0):

Not all variables work inside of `ini_set` and `upload_tmp_dir` is one of them because it must be set before PHP executes. You can this variable in either the `php.ini` file directly or by adding it to your `.htaccess` file like so: `php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /new/temp/path`